# Are rare spawn chances higher on higher difficulties?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

(Some) Dungeons have rare spawns. They have a low chance of randomly replacing one of the enemies in a Dungeon. Are they more likely to appear on higher difficulties (of the same Dungeon)?

Answer (score -1):

Typically, drop rates will be higher for the higher difficulties.
You can see drop rates at pad.wikia.com

For example, in [The Thief Descended!](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/The_Thief_Descended!), Goemon has a 40% drop rate in Legend difficulty but 100% drop rate in Mythical.

Comment: I'm not asking about drop rates.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question.  Unfortunately I don't know the answer to this.  I tried looking on a few sites but couldn't find any information.  Should I delete this answer?  I'm not sure what the policy is on that.

Comment: You can leave it up if you wish. I down-voted it because it fulfills the criteria for a down-vote, but retracted my vote because you were trying to be helpful anyway. Your reply comment alone is relevant and useful.